# How to access a directive from a service in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

NOTE: I'm using Angula **rc2**

My Goal is: to **set a property value in the directive from the service**

I set up a custom directive which uses a service:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[chooseFile]'
})

@Injectable()
export class ChooseFileDirective implements OnInit {
  property1: number = 1;

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _uploadService: UploadFile) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._uploadService.foo();
  }    
}
```

**UploadService**

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadFile {

  constructor(private _chooseFileDirective: ChooseFileDirective) {}

  foo() {
    // update variable on calling directive
    _chooseFileDirective.property1++;
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> Error: (SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UploadFile: (?)

What I tried (single and all together):

- add @Injectable() decorator in the directive
- add the directives to providers in app.component
- add in service's constructor: @Inject(ChooseFileDirective) _chooseFileDirective: ChooseFileDirective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 doesn't allow to inject directives/components. It will be right a way to directive listen to service. 
You can create an EventEmitter representing for example fileUploaded$ event, so in directive you can do something like this:

```
export class ChooseFileDirective implements OnInit {
  property1: number = 1;

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _uploadService: UploadFile) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._uploadService.foo();
    this.fileUploaded$.subscribe(file => //do your stuff)
  }    
}
```